# The drawable image from ImageView component as a params

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want the drawable image from ImageView component as a params,so I can change it in other class.This is my main class code:

```
private void StartData(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> List, int Resource) {
    this.Adapter = new BasicAdapter2(getActivity(), List, Resource,
            new String[] { "Provider", "ProdName", "NoType", "ContractNo",
                    "AcceptTime", "ContractStatus", "Premium", "Gain",
                    "ReceivedPremium", "Name" }, 
            new int[] {R.id.contractitem_label_Provider,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_ProdName,
                    R.id.contract_label_cno,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_contractNo,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_acceptTime,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_contractStatus,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_premium,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_feilv,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_receivedPremium,
                    R.id.contractitem_label_Name }, 
            new int[] {R.id.listitem_button_look, R.id.listitem_button_pay,
        R.id.listitem_main1,R.id.contractitem_label_companyImage,R.id.contractitem_label_payImage },
            new BasicAdapter2.ListAdapterListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClickAtOKButton(View v) {
                    String company = dTable.GetValue((Integer)v.getTag(), 1).toString();
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.listitem_button_pay:
                        if (company.contains("xx")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"xxxxx", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        String polnum = dTable.GetValue((Integer)v.getTag(), 3).toString();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(getActivity(),PolicyInformationActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("polnum", polnum);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.listitem_button_look:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"cccc...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.listitem_main1:
                        break;
                    }

                }
            },
            new BasicAdapter2.VisibleAdapterListener() {

                @Override
                public int onSetVisible(View v) {
                    String company = dTable.GetValue((Integer)v.getTag(), 1).toString();
                    int drawId;
                    if (company.contains("xx")) {
                        drawId = getResources().getInteger(R.drawable.taikang2x);
                        LogUtil.e("tai=========", drawId+"1");
                        return drawId;
                    } else if (company.contains("yy")) {
                        drawId = getResources().getInteger(R.drawable.youban2x);
                        LogUtil.e("you=========", drawId+"1");
                        return drawId;
                    } else {
                    return 0;
                    }
                }
            });

    handler = new Handler();
    this.Adapter.Start(this.MainView);
    this.Start += Step;
    this.End += Step;
    this.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class BasicAdapter2 extends SimpleAdapter {

Context context;
private ArrayList<Integer> Indexs;
private ListAdapterListener mListener;
private VisibleAdapterListener vListener;

 public interface ListAdapterListener { // create an interface
        void onClickAtOKButton(View v); // create callback function
    }
 public interface VisibleAdapterListener { // create an interface
        int onSetVisible(View v); // create callback function
    }
public BasicAdapter2(Context context,List<? extends Map<String,?>> data,
        int resource,String[] from,int[] to,ListAdapterListener mListener){
    super(context,data,resource,from,to);
    this.context=context;
    this.Indexs =new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

public BasicAdapter2(Context context,List<? extends Map<String,?>> data,
        int resource,String[] from,int[] to,int[] Ids,
        ListAdapterListener mListener,VisibleAdapterListener vListener){
    super(context,data,resource,from,to);
    this.context=context;
    this.Indexs =new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.mListener = mListener;
    if (Ids != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++) {
            this.Indexs.add(Ids[i]);
        }
    }
}

public void Add(Integer ViewId){this.Indexs.add(ViewId);}

@Override
public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    for(int i=0;i<this.Indexs.size();i++){
        final View TempView=(View) view.findViewById(this.Indexs.get(i));
        TempView.setOnClickListener(new View .OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onClickAtOKButton(TempView);
            }
        });
        TempView.setTag(position);
        TempView.setBackgroundResource(vListener.onSetVisible(TempView));
    }
    return view;
}
public void Start(ListView View){
    View.setAdapter(this);
    this.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {  
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view,Object data,String textRepresentation) {    
            if(view instanceof TextView && data instanceof HkBoolean){
                HkBoolean Data = (HkBoolean) data;
                view.setVisibility(Data.GetVisibility());
                return true;
            }else if(view instanceof ImageView && data instanceof Bitmap){    
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;    
                iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data);    
                return true;    
            }else if(view instanceof ImageView && data instanceof Integer){    
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;    
                iv.setBackgroundResource((Integer) data);    
                return true;    
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }    
    });
}

}
```

In my main class,I try "drawId = getResources().getInteger(R.drawable.taikang2x);" and "drawId = R.drawable.taikang2x;" ,but "NullPointerException".What went wrong?

Comment: you cannot fount integer in R.drawable.taikang2x field. getInteger return integer in <integer> tag.

Comment: I'm so sorry,I found the wrong ,I just forgot"this.vListener = vListener;"and "drawId = R.drawable.taikang2x;" can work.Thanks all the same.